# Use jsencrypt.js to encrypt message, when message's length over 53 then results false

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am using jsencrypt.js to encrypt a string in javascript, it does well in short message, when message.length>53 then results false.(my message's length is 58)
I had searched Internet but it's not useful.
So maybe I can change the codes in web service but it hard to change. I think maybe there are some methods can figure out the problem, but I don't know how to do.

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(PrivateKey);
var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(content);
alert(encrypted);
```

use jsencrypt.js to encrypt content with PrivateKey. And the content's length is 58.

Comment: you should add your code to the question or we can't help you properly.

Comment: @Hoi_A I have edited my question, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Public key encryption (asymmetric encryption) limits the data to less than the key length. The data is generally padded for security which reduces the data length even further. Asymmetric encryption is also substantially slower than symmetric key encryption. Asymmetric key encryption is generally used to encrypt keys.

Unless there is a compelling need for a public/private key pair use symmetric key encryption such as AES to encrypt data. Symmetric key encryption is designed to be fast and handle large data.

Comment: it doesn't work when I increase the length of key, and it still limited in length 53.